# Getting ad bid estimates (reach/delivery) using the Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

We are trying to get the bid estimation curve of an Ad Account programmatically using the Facebook Ads Python SDK v2.9.

In v2.8 it used to work, but does not work in v2.9 (see examples below). Any ideas?

Return value v2.9:

```
"daily_outcomes_curve": [
    {
      "spend": 0,
      "reach": 0,
      "impressions": 0,
      "actions": 0
    }
  ]
```

Return value 2.8:

```
"curve": [{
            "bid": 0,
            "spend": 0,
            "reach": 0,
            "impressions": 0,
            "actions": 0,
            "predicted_errors_conversions": 1,
            "predicted_errors_reach": 1,
            "reach_lower_bound": 0,
            "reach_upper_bound": 0,
            "actions_lower_bound": 0,
            "actions_upper_bound": 0
        },
        {
            "bid": 1,
            "spend": 646,
            "reach": 3567.9354838954,
            "impressions": 6680.7097528277,
            "actions": 130.80274455903,
            "predicted_errors_conversions": 2.8245606972256,
            "predicted_errors_reach": 2.689207357674,
            "reach_lower_bound": 1263.9466935967,
            "reach_upper_bound": 9763.8390907652,
            "actions_lower_bound": 39.849431346027,
            "actions_upper_bound": 387.70589834293
        },
```

Comment: please share the request you are making to generate this response

Comment: Below is the request (I removed the account ID and access_token):

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_{account}/delivery_estimate?access_token={acces_token}&&method=get&optimization_goal=POST_ENGAGEMENT&targeting_spec={ "geo_locations": {"countries": ["US"] }, "age_min": 20, "age_max": 60}

Answer (score 1):

Using v2.9, I executed the below request and was able to retrieve results:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_<ID>/delivery_estimate?optimization_goal=POST_ENGAGEMENT&targeting_spec=%7B%20%22geo_locations%22%3A%20%7B%22countries%22%3A%20%5B%22US%22%5D%20%7D%2C%20%22age_min%22%3A%2020%2C%20%22age_max%22%3A%2060%7D&access_token="
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "bid_estimate": {
        "min_bid": 51,
        "median_bid": 67,
        "max_bid": 95
      },
      "daily_outcomes_curve": [
        {
          "bid": 0,
          "spend": 0,
          "reach": 0,
          "impressions": 0,
          "actions": 0
        },
        {
          "bid": 1,
          "spend": 435,
          "reach": 4484.0916784657,
          "impressions": 4538.5274241599,
          "actions": 96.207167683919
        },
...
```

Most probably you received some intermittent failure.

Comment: With exactly the same call as the above I get the following response:

{
   "data": [
      {
         "bid_estimate": {
            "min_bid": 158,
            "median_bid": 207,
            "max_bid": 299
         },
         "daily_outcomes_curve": [
            {
               "spend": 0,
               "reach": 0,
               "impressions": 0,
               "actions": 0
            }
         ],
         "estimate_dau": 0,
         "estimate_mau": 175000000,
         "estimate_ready": true
      }
   ]

Comment: @hrom - was this still against your sandbox account?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with real accounts. Only zeros in the daily_outcomes_curve.

Comment: @ViktorKärnstrand I have tested above request and also get the curve array with only one object having all zeros. Interestingly, when I create an actual adset, (with same values) under an actual campaign, I get a nice looking set of points in the curve array. (granted that my `targeting_spec` is specified enough and even sandbox account can return full set of curve points)

Comment: how can we evaluate the estimates from this array set?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I found this in the API documentation, it might help someone else who winds up here

> This field will only have data when we are able to provide high confidence predictions. When we do not have high confidence predictions we will return an array of 1 point with all 0s.

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-delivery-estimate/